# Complicated string data extraction

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract data from given strings, I've managed to do so yet I've encountered some difficulties.

I'll give you two strings:

```
"ESS23300RGR","Boorum & Pease 23 Series Columnar Book, Record, 300 Page, Black/Red (23-300-R)","UnbeatableSale, Inc (Amazon Marketplace)","180.80","6.09","http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B000DLBVU4/ref=olp_page_next?ie=UTF8&shipPromoFilter=0&startIndex=15&sort=sip&me=&condition=new","http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B000DLBVU4/ref=olp_page_next?ie=UTF8&shipPromoFilter=0&startIndex=15&sort=sip&me=&condition=new"
"WLJ36210WGR","Basic Round Ring View Binder, 362 Line, 3 Ring, 1" Capacity, 8-1/2" x 5-1/2" Sheet Size, White","Gov Group (Amazon Marketplace)","3.61","7.70","http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B0006OF55A/ref=olp_seeall_fm?ie=UTF8&shipPromoFilter=0&startIndex=0&sort=sip&me=&condition=new","http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B0006OF55A/ref=olp_seeall_fm?ie=UTF8&shipPromoFilter=0&startIndex=0&sort=sip&me=&condition=new"
```

This is the expression I've used:regexChecker(**"[\w\s&\(\)-^,]{3,}"**, longString);

Using it I've managed to separated perfectly the first string yet the second one not, since it uses , and " as part of some sections.

How can I extract the data from the second string similar to the first one?

Data needed to be extracted is: SKU,Name,Competitor,Price,Shipping,URL,SourceURL

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just add backslash before comma in your regex

Comment: Extracted like this SKU,Name,Competitor,Price,Shipping,URL,SourceURL or like: "SKU","Name","Competitor", etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
String[] tabS = myLine.substring(1, myLine.lenght() -1).split("\",\"");
```

to remove all significant `"`

Comment: Yes, the problem is the unescape `1" Capacity` quote.

Comment: @PaulVargas Here you remove the first and the last `"`, then you putthe words between `","` in a array. is it a good solution ?

Comment: Good. Hopefully this will work properly. The CSV is not properly escaped.

Comment: The problem is the _3_ unescaped quotes in `1" Capacity, 8-1/2" x 5-1/2"`.

Comment: @MRAB it seems this it not the problem for OP. You can remove them with somethiong like `String result = tabS[i].trim().replaceAll("\"", "");`

Answer (score 0):

Check following code. It gave me desired results for both of your input strings.

```
StringBuilder testt = new StringBuilder("\"ESS23300RGR\",\"Boorum & Pease 23 Series Columnar Book, Record, 300 Page, Black/Red (23-300-R)\",\"UnbeatableSale, Inc (Amazon Marketplace)\",\"180.80\",\"6.09\",\"http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000DLBVU4\",\"http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000DLBVU4\"");

 Pattern varPattern = Pattern.compile(",\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

 Matcher varMatcher = varPattern.matcher(testt);

 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

 int startIndex = 0, endIndex = 0;
 boolean found = false;

 while (varMatcher.find()) {
  endIndex = varMatcher.start();
  if (startIndex == 0) {
   list.add(testt.substring(startIndex, endIndex));
  } else {
   list.add(testt.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex));
  }
  startIndex = varMatcher.start();
  found = true;
 }
 if (found) {
  if (startIndex == 0) {
   list.add(testt.substring(startIndex));
  } else {
   list.add(testt.substring(startIndex + 1));
  }
 }
 for (String s : list) {
  System.out.println(s);
 }
}
```